# Calling api with different parameters on button click and passing it to cell for row it indexpath in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I have a controller class which consist of a tableview inside in it. In the controller I have a searchbar and 5 buttons. When I run my application for the first time I want the first button to remain selected.

When the button is clicked I am calling a JSON api from server and depending on the values returned from JSON I want to display in my tableview. When the second button is clicked the same function is called but by passing different parameter as id to it. I have done the code but the problem when the application is run for the first time the first button is shown selected and it's api is getting called but when I switch to next button my tableview does not get refreshed with the new values.

I have 5 buttons which I have added to my to my controller class. When I run my application for the first time I want the first button to remain selected and its action to be performed and api to be called and when second button is clicked second action should be performed an so on and same should be reflected on tableview depending on results when particular button is clicked.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    category = [[ResultJson alloc] init];
    dealsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnAll];
    [btnAll setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-1-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ([[btnAll backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-1-active.png"]])
    {
        [self btnAll]; 
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];

 }


-(IBAction)btnAll
{
    [self.tblView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Done");
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnAll];
    if (category.newArray)
    {
        [category.newArray release];
    }
    category.newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [btnAll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [btnAll setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-1-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnEntertainment setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnRetail setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnServices setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnFood setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnHealthBeauty setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [category GetDetails:1];
    [dealsArray addObjectsFromArray:category.newArray];
    btnAll.tag = 0;

}


-(IBAction)btnEntertainment
{
    [self.tblView reloadData];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnEntertainment];
    if (category.newArray)
    {
        [category.newArray release];
    }
    category.newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [btnEntertainment setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-2-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnAll setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnRetail setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnHealthBeauty setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnServices setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnFood setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [category GetDetails:2];


    [dealsArray addObjectsFromArray:category.newArray];
    btnEntertainment.tag = 1;

}
```

This is my first 2 button action where I am calling the GetDetails api method by passing an id as a parameter to it. Initially in ViewDidload I am setting my first btnAll as selected and performing its action but the problem is when I click on the second button the results of the first button are shown on the tableview and on second time clicking the second button its results are visible in tableview.

Comment: Show your effort here(code). So someone can help you..

Comment: Probably you are missing the call of reloadData on your UItableView once the results are available.

Comment: will you plz provide some code, i think you missing [tableView reloadData]; and make sure your array has updated data.

Comment: Yes. This could be possible you are missing to reload tableview.

Comment: @Nit i have added code in my question.Please check it.

Comment: @MayurBirari i have added code in my question.Please chec

Answer (score 1):

What ever you want to do and as i understood in your in your question. I like to tell you three things.

1)Add `[yourtablview reloadData];` when you need to refresh table with new data.

2) Set different tag for all button according to your category before you call button action

3) Use `IBAction` following way

```
 -(IBAction)btnEntertainment:(id)sender // here i used action name `btnEntertainment`. you can use your action name.
     {
       int buttonidentifier = [sender tag];// this will give button tag so you can identify which button clicked or tapped and call you api your according to that like below.

       if(buttonidentifier == 1)//this tag will give you button identification. For example you set tag 1 for `button1` than this is indicate that you first button is tapped or click.
         {
           // call first category api and do whatever you want do 
          }

      else if(buttonidentifier == 2)//this tag will give you button identification. For example you set tag 2 for `button2` than this is indicate that you second button is tapped or click.
         {
           // call Second category api and do whatever you want do 
          }
      }
```

**>> Edited Addition**

You have set button tag when you create button your in viewdidload. You don't need to write another action for every button this same action will work for all button and it will identify which button is tapped or click using button tag(`buttonidentifier`) as shown in my code.

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: as u have done for btnEntertainment Same code i hav to write for other button actions also

Comment: where should i set the tag of every button in viewDidLoad

Comment: You have set button tag when you create button your in viewdidload. You don't need to write another action for every button this same action will work for all button and it will identify using button tag

Comment: Read my full answer again and you will get idea. I have also added new comment in if contain part. So please read whole answer again...enjoy..:)

Answer (score 0):

one this that you have to check that how you are testing the first use of application, if it is dependent on different users, then save their some unique id alongwith YEs in NSDefaults, such as

```
[[NSDefulsts standardDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:someUserID];
[NSDefulsts standardDefaults] synchronize];
```

and at get time check the same id as

```
[[NSDefulsts standardDefaults] getBoolForKey:someUserID]
```

if not user then any variable like

```
[[NSDefulsts standardDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:isFirstTime];
```

and for your 2nd question, whenever you want your tableveiew to reload, call

```
[tablview reloadData];
```

you will call this each time when your request is finished and you set the values of jSON to some aray or dictonary